# How to use rsnapshot with limited/no cache?

Tags: cache, rsnapshot

So I have RSnapshot configured but I have been running into issues, when I try to backup my (whole) system I run out of storage becuase RSnapshot is using it to cache. Is there a way for me to use a small cache (like 10-40GB) or no cache?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "caching". Please post your rsnapshot config.

Comment: I can post it but what I mean by cache is it copies all files to a dir before uploading which causes my PC to run out of memory.

Comment: That's nuts. Yeah posting you conf would help.

Comment: Will do when nvidia works...